# ecto failing to create table in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, migration, phoenix-framework, ecto

I am using Phoenix framework and following along in book programming phoenix.
The project was created using `mix`. The relevant config for the database user and password were updated as necessary. 
The following commands are entered and the model defined
A model of users - this follows the example in the book:

```
defmodule Rumbl.User do

    use Rumbl.Web, :model
    schema "users" do
        field :name, :string
        field :username, :string
        field :password, :string, virtual: true
        field :password_hash, :string
        timestamps
    end
end
```

The steps of:

1. `mix ecto.create`
2. `mix ecto.gen.migration create_user`

   Generates a xxxx_create_user.exs file
3. `mix ecto.migrate`

   Produces the update to schema_migrations but does not create the user table in PostgreSQL.

Curious as to what I might be doing wrong here.

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Comment: No errors. Have started from scratch and still no success.

Comment: What is the content of your `xxxx_create_user.exs`?

Comment: Apparently the generated create_user.exs file doesn't create the table and fields...

defmodule Rumbl.Repo.Migrations.CreateUser do

  use Ecto.Migration


  def change do

  end
end

Answer (score 1):

After you run `mix ecto.gen.migration create_user` command, you will get a migration file doing nothing to the database.

You need to [create](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Migration.html#create/2) the table yourself in the generated migration file:

```
  def change do
    create table(:users) do
      add :name, :string
      add :username, :string
      add :password_hash, :string

      timestamps()
    end
  end
```

After that, running `mix ecto.migration` should modify your database schema as you wish.